# How can I use Xcode to compile a C program so I can use the binary in the sandbox?

Tags: c, swift, xcode, sandbox, entitlements

I have a Cocoa app that runs a binary executable I include with the project, unless I turn sandboxing on. I want sandboxing on, so I need a way to authorize the running of this program. I have the source code - this binary executable is part of a big package which comes with a shell script for making the software along with a bunch of other programs. It compiles successfully using this script on my Mac.

I found another post on stackoverflow where it was suggested that the C code can be compiled within XCode along with the rest of the app and it will be allowed to execute that way.

Is that true? I would like to compile the C code as part of my app and run the binary executable it creates.

Comment: You can embed the binary with your app and as long as it's signed with the same certificate as the app you can run it with sandboxing turned on.  There must be something at the Apple Developer site about this somewhere...

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok, thanks, that points me in the right direction. Now to find out how to compile it in Xcode using the existing make script.

Comment: Throw away the makefile.  Just add a new target to the Xcode project and it should be easy to configure.

Comment: I'll do that and see where it goes. The executable I need is normally compiled along with a bunch of other things as part of a kind of big library (NCBI's C toolkit). I just tried to codesign the binary executable using `codesign -s "Me" theBinary` and accessing it from my app using `Bundle.main.url(forAuxiliaryExecutable: "theBinary")` but it is still failing and reporting 'must provide a launch path' and then a trace of some other notes in ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

As suggested by trojanfoe, codesigning worked.

`codesign -s "Me" theBinary`

the problem was my Swift line,

`Bundle.main.url(forAuxiliaryExecutable: "theBinary")`

I changed it to,

`Bundle.main.url(forResource: "theBinary", withExtension: nil)`

and now it works. Alright! Only cost me $99.